# Problem with enabling the Optimizing js files

Tags: performance, drupal-6

I have installed the events and signup modules. The events appears in a calender. All were working fine. But when I enabled the optimizing JS files on the performance page Now the events does not display for the anonymous and authentication user. Now they are only available for the administrator.
I again the disabled the optimizing JS files on performance page but still events are not displaying.

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have nothing to do with performance, try to check user permissions for events functionality first.

The only problem with optimizing JS you could get - it's JS not working, not the events.

So check permissions and clear cache.